# How to make a disabled reactive form Editable in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I am Using below code to create a form and make it readOnly, I am new to angular

```
createForm() {
        this.comapnyIdentificationForm = this.fb.group({
          businessName: ['', Validators.required ],
          adressPrimary: '',
          adressSecondary: '',
          city:'',
          state: '',
          zipCode: '',
          country: '',
          companyPhone: '',
          DUNS: ''
        });
         this.comapnyIdentificationForm.disable();
      }
```

I need to make it enabled and post edited data back to Json :

```
<button type="button"  (click)="EditData()" class="btn modal-btn btn-default">Edit</button>
```

Comment: You really need to post more data then this. How you make it readonly for example

Comment: `this.comapnyIdentificationForm.disable()`, just at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use following code to enable your form .

```
this.comapnyIdentificationForm.enable();
```

To get a json object. Use following code:

```
this.comapnyIdentificationForm.value;
```

To fill-up your form with backend data use following code:
this.comapnyIdentificationForm.patchValue(jsonData);

Comment: I get data from JSON for different fields and if someone wants edit then need to send it back updated

Comment: Do you want to update your form with json data? Can you please properly describe so that I can help you better

Comment: On my tab 1st the data comes from backend json, and then i have a button for Edit this data , which enables the filed to be edited , and then if changes are made then need to resubmit the form data back to Backend json (post)

Comment: I update my answer for your use case. If still you need help then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a directive too

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[enableControl]'
})
export class EnableControlDirective {
  @Input() set enableControl( condition : boolean ) {
    if (condition)
        this.ngControl.control.enable();
    else
      this.ngControl.control.disable();
  }

  constructor(private ngControl : NgControl ) {}
}

//use
<input class="form-control " [enableControl]="condition">
```