# Disable Angular Reactive form input based on selection value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form (using Angular Material), and I want to disable some of the input fields based on selection values. My code looks as below:

HTML

```html
<mat-form-field class="someclass">
   <mat-select placeholder="Select payment method" formControlName="paymentMethod">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let payment of paymentMethodOptions" [value]="payment.value">
         {{payment.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="someclass">
   <input matInput placeholder="Some input" formControlName="testInput">
</mat-form-field>
```

TS

```js
paymentMethodOptions: payment[] = [
   { value: "opt-1", viewValue: "somevalue" },
   { value: "opt-2", viewValue: "anothervalue" }
];

paymentForm = new FormGroup({
   paymentMethod: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
   testInput: new FormControl({ value: "", disabled: true }, [
      Validators.required
   ])
});
```

I want to disable `testInput` if the value of the selection is equal to `"opt-1"`. I've tried several options, but got different errors and couldn't solve it. Is there any working solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I like a enabledDirective (it's looks like a work-around, but it have tha advantage that is the .html with control the enabled) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937639/how-to-make-a-disabled-reactive-form-editable-in-angular2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage the `selectionChange` `@Output` property on `MatSelect` and react accordingly:

```
onSelectionChanged({value}) {
  console.log(value);
  if(value === 'opt-1') {
    this.paymentForm.get('testInput').disable();
  } else {
    this.paymentForm.get('testInput').enable();
  }
}
```

And in template

```
<mat-select ... (selectionChange)="onSelectionChanged($event)">
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-form-field-on-select-value?file=app/form-field-overview-example.html) for your ref.

**NOTE:** In case there are more controls in your form than just `mat-select`, listening to `valueChanges` on the whole form could be expensive as this will get triggered every time there is a change in any of the form control. All we are concerned about is the change in the `mat-select` selection change.

Comment: @Andrew, if any of these answers helped you with your issue please consider marking any one of them as a solution to close the loop.

Answer (score 7):

You'll can listen to the `valueChanges` event of the form :

```
this.paymentForm.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
  if(value.paymentMethod == 'opt-1'){
   this.paymentForm.controls['testInput'].disable();
  }else{
   this.paymentForm.controls['testInput'].enable();
  }
});
```

So everytime the `select` changes , the `valueChanges` event is called , the conditions kick in and it will enable or disable the formControl.

Comment: Looks like your solution works too. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you listening to `valueChanges` on the whole form? Won't it run every time there's any change on the form? We should only be concerned with the `mat-select` value change here.

Comment: @SiddAjmera formControl is bound to the select . Else i would have used the ``selectionChange`` event too .

Comment: Wouldn't it be safe to assume that OP was a mere abstraction of the original implementation and that there are going to be a lot more form controls in the form rather than just a `mat-select`?

Comment: @SiddAjmera , i agree with what you are trying to say but if we go on with the assumption then there maybe a case where he may wants to persist the valueChange and make api calls too .

Comment: Point. I take my words back in that case. Sorry about that. :)

Comment: @SiddAjmera no problem :)

Comment: Both solutions work good, will try using both of them and decide which one suits my case better. Thanks for your support :)

Comment: @Andrew happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Though there are already answers provided, If any had stumbled with the same issue. You can directly disable a form field by directly accessing its control

Had created a Stackblitz demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-reference-control-disable-input)

```
  <!-- INPUT FIELD --> 
  <mat-form-field formControlName="testInput">
    <input matInput 
           placeholder="Some input"
           [disabled]="paymentForm.get('paymentMethod').value === 'opt-1'">   // Disables the input once paymentMethod's formControlName value is opt-1    
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. You'll have to use `attr.disabled` in this case. Also it did not change the `disabled` state if `opt-1` was selected first and then `opt-2` is selected.

Comment: Had accidentally removed the [disabled] on input from the Stackblitz demo link i sent. Now it actually changes its state, you can try it. You'll know it gets disabled when you can't click on the input anymore and it has a dotted border instead of solid

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuygok

Comment: Indeed it works. So the trick is to use `paymentForm.get('paymentMethod').value` instead of `paymentForm.value.paymentMethod`