# Error Binding element 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {startWith, map} from 'rxjs/operators';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Test';

  
  answers: any = [
    {value: '0', viewValue: 'Yes'},
    {value: '1', viewValue: 'No'}
  ];

  customerdataForm = new FormGroup({
    answerControl: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
    sapNumberControl: new FormControl({value: "", disabled: true}, [
      Validators.required
    ])
  });

  onSelectionChanged({ value } ) {
    console.log(value);
    if (value === '0') {
      console.log("true");
      this.customerdataForm.get('sapNumberControl')?.disable;
    } else {
      console.log("false");
      this.customerdataForm.get('sapNumberControl')?.enable();
    }
  }

}
export class InputForm{}
```

In this code im getting the error

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:29:24 - error TS7031: Binding element 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

This code is also from a
[Stackoverflow Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406344/disable-angular-reactive-form-input-based-on-selection-value)

Where it also works in a
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-form-field-on-select-value?file=app/form-field-overview-example.html)

Can anyone help?

I dont know where this error comes from and i tried now many things, nothin worked

EDIT:

Trying to implement the same functionality as described in the mentioned stackoverflow discussion

Used html

```
          <form [formGroup]="customerdataForm">
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
              <mat-select formControlName="answerControl" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChanged($event)">
                <!-- <mat-option>--</mat-option> -->
                <mat-option *ngFor="let answer of answers" [value]="answer">
                  {{answer.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
            <p>Customer SAP (only if they are an existing customer)</p>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Customer_SAP" formControlName="sapNumberControl">
            </mat-form-field>
          </form>
```

Comment: Share your HTML please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is in the function `onSelectionChanged({ value } ) {}` try adding a type to `value` If you know the type of what you are getting, I think its a string so try with string or any

`onSelectionChanged(value: string ) { }`

You need to specify the types of the variables you are using in TS as its a strongly typed language.

Edit: also take out the `{ }` from `value`

Comment: solved the problem and youre answer helped very. thanks