# Dynamic Validations in Angular 7: enable() & setValidators depending on flags triggered by changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, optimization, angular-reactive-forms

My last Angular project was a long time ago, I've worked with VueJS meanwhile. Now I am back and implemented a reactive form with some conditional fields in Angular 7.

My solution below works, I can enable fields or set validators dependend on flags. But somehow I don't like this solution, it is too long and not intuitive. No one can intuit, that you have to disable a field to disable validators. Can an Angular/TypeScript expert help me to **optimize that code or do it right way**?

```
onChangeType(scope: string) {
    console.log(scope);
    this.myForm.get('riskType').disable();
    this.myForm.get('chancheType').disable();

    if (scope === 'local') {
    this.flags.isScopeLocal = true;
    this.flags.isScopeTemplate = false;
    this.flags.isScopeGlobal = false;
    this.myForm.get('chancheType').enable();
    this.myForm.get('chancheType').setValidators(Validators.required);
    } else if (scope === 'template') {
    this.flags.isScopeTemplate = true;
    this.flags.isScopeLocal = false;
    this.flags.isScopeGlobal = false;
    this.myForm.get('riskType').enable();
    this.myForm.get('riskType').setValidators(Validators.required);
    } else {
    // global
    this.flags.isScopeLocal = false;
    this.flags.isScopeTemplate = false;
    this.flags.isScopeGlobal = true;
    this.myForm.get('riskType').disable();
    this.myForm.get('chancheType').disable();
    }
}
```

Short explenation: If scope is local or template there will be a new reqired field. If scope is global then disappears this field and its validator will be deactivated.

Comment: If a control is not enabled, not check the validation (e.g. all inputs disabled, the form is valid). For disabled a control, you can not use [disabled]="..." nor [attr.disabled], but you can use a directive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937639/how-to-make-a-disabled-reactive-form-editable-in-angular2

Comment: thank you @Eliseo but, that is not my problem,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementary my comment using a directive [How to make a disabled reactive form Editable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937639/how-to-make-a-disabled-reactive-form-editable-in-angular2)

Lonely, you needn't change the validators using setValidators, and the directive is who enabled/disabled the controls. I think is more "readable"

```
<input formControlName="riskType" [enabledControl]="scope=='local'">
<input formControlName="chancheType" [enabledControl]="scope=='template'">

myForm=this.fb.group({
     riskType:['',Validators.required],
     cacheType:['',Validators.required],

})
```

Comment: big problem with AngularMaterial: `Can't bind to 'enabledControl' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-select'.`

Comment: Lonely, You need import in your main.ts the directive, More, take account that the directive is only apply a NgControl (one input with [(ngModel)] or a input with FromControl or FormControlName). see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq4x4r?file=app%2Fselect-disabled-example.html. Really if you use material you can use directly the property [disabled]