# Unable to setValidators(Validators.required) from parent component to child component

Tags: angular, nested-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form which consist of a checkbox and a component named address. So whenever user click the checkbox app should set the address to required field. This is my HTML.

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
   <app-address-input formControlName="address"></app-address-input><br>
   <input type="checkbox" formControlName="check"> Check?
</form>
<p>Form value: {{ registerForm.value | json }}</p>
<p>Form status: {{ registerForm.status | json }}</p>
```

This is my component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {
  registerForm = new FormGroup({
      address: new FormControl(undefined),
      check: new FormControl(undefined)
  });
  get address() {
      return this.registerForm.get('address')
  }
  get check() {
      return this.registerForm.get('check')
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
      this.registerForm.get('check').valueChanges.pipe(tap(val => {
      if(val){
            this.registerForm.get('address').setValidators(Validators.required)
       }
        this.registerForm.get('address').updateValueAndValidity();
      })).subscribe();
   }
}
```

Comment: Here's the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t3q6pp

Comment: why using setValidators? I think it's better aproach disable the controls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517613/dynamic-validations-in-angular-7-enable-setvalidators-depending-on-flags-tr/54518185#comment96057196_54518185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should subscribe to the valueChanges of the form control in **ngOnInit** instead of **ngOnChanges**

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.registerForm.get('check').valueChanges.subscribe( (val) => {
           if(val){
              console.log(val)
                 this.registerForm.get('address').setValidators(Validators.required)
            }
            this.registerForm.get('address').updateValueAndValidity();
            console.log(this.registerForm.valid);         
         });
 }
```

Your component doesn't have any @Input(), so the **ngOnChanges** life cycle won't get invoked. so the subscribe of the form control can't work. You should subscribe the form control in **ngOnInit**, so that the valueChanges of the form control gets subscribed.

Difference between these two life cycles explained in Angular Docs

**ngOnChanges**

> Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives >a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values.
>   Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties >change.

**ngOnInit**

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound >properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.
>   Called once, after the first ngOnChanges().

Comment: I think it's more "natural" disable the controls :)

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing wrong in your code, why your subscription is not working means you have to subscribe on ngOnInit() not in ngOnChanges() lifecycle hook.

ngOnChanges() invoked whenever @Input param values changes.

For any kind subscription (if you wish to listen some changes or subscribe). It is advisable to put that subscription in the ngOnInit() life cycle.

**Note : Don't forget to unsubscribe the subscription at the ngOnDestroy() lifecycle hook.
it would save your code from any kind of memory leak, even though angular handles it..**