# Angular 6 - unable to disable input textbox

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I would like to disable my textbox when a checkbox is checked. Problem is, I can't even disable it in the first place without any condition.

This is my HTML:

```
<label for="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox other" name="others" value="15"
        #goodsOthersChk (change)="onCheckArray($event, Form.value.goods)">
    <p class="otherText"> Others:</p>
    <input id="goodsOthers" name="goodsOthers"
        formControlName="goodsOthers" type="text" value=""
        class="form-control otherInput" size="30%" [disabled]="isDisabled">
</label>
```

my component.ts:

```
export class GoodsComponent implements OnInit {
  isDisabled = true;
}
```

I don't see what I'm missing. When I inspect the textbox, it has a property of `ng-reflect-is-disabled` which is set to true but does not reflect on my page.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uazb2n it's working..... can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: @PranavCBalan i reproduced and it works as expected but it doesn't on my page

Comment: problem is related something else in your code.... share full code

Comment: I see a `formControlName` directive on it. The [disabled] property will not work with Reactive Forms. Use the disabled property on the FormControl in TypeScript instead.

Comment: @cristian.t is correct. You should not use the `[disabled]` property to disable a form control using reactive forms. Currently it gives a warning in console, later this will be deprecated and give errors.

Comment: I mean, I'm literally guessing. Hard to tell what is happening, we're only seeing a small snippet of the real code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937639/how-to-make-a-disabled-reactive-form-editable-in-angular2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is because you are using Reactive Forms. Theoretically speaking, you can use the `disabled` attribute, but the Reactive Form way of doing things would be to set the `disabled` property when you initialise the FormGroup.

```
yourFrom: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  goodsOthers: [{ value: null, disabled: true }],
  .
  .
  // other Form controls
})
```

[Other FormControl properties](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#formcontrol)

Comment: hi this works. thanks! btw, i would like to toggle between disable and enable a textbox using a checkbox. how can i do this if i have more than one textbox which i need to apply it to? i am able to do it for one but am not entirely sure how to do it for more than one

Comment: You're welcome! I see. Is each textbox 'connected' to its own individual checkbox? Or are you using this single checkbox to toggle the disabled attribute of all textboxes?

Comment: @mhfour I'll get back to you soon after my working hours

Comment: hi, i just remembered about this and was wondering if there was a way to do this?

Comment: @mhfour Sorry for the late reply. Have you thought of grouping the input and its corresponding checkbox in a FormGroup?

Comment: do you mean each input and its checkbox should be grouped in their own FormGroup? currently, everything is in one FormGroup

Comment: @mhfour I will post a short snippet on my answer shortly. Just to check, how many of those input/checkbox pairs are there on your form?

Comment: i have a few forms and it varies from form to form. there is at least 5 per form

Comment: hi, are you able to post the snippet?