# Disabled value is not rendering

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-ngselect

Setting **disabled** attribute *by template* works correctly, but the console shows this warning:

[image: disabled warning]

```
<... ... name="Province" id="name="Province" formControlName="Province" [disabled]="this.listValues.length==0">
```

So, my solution coming through code it in the back (*.ts file*):

```
  this.listValues= regions;
  if (this.listValues.length === 0) {
    this.registerForm.get('Province').disable();
  } else {
    this.registerForm.get('Province').enable();
  }
```

Debugging the code I can confirm that the control (Province) is changing its state from disabled to enabled and so on, but *the html* is not rendering this values/changes.

Also tried:

```
<... ... name="Province" id="name="Province" formControlName="Province" [attr.disabled]="this.listValues.length==0">
```

and:

```
...
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Province: [{ value: '', disabled: this.listValues.length===0}, null],
....
```

or:

```
  this.listValues= regions;
  if (this.listValues.length === 0) {
    this.registerForm.controls['Province'].disable();
  } else {
    this.registerForm.controls['Province'].enable();
  }
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: `[disabled]="registerForm.get('Province').disabled"`

Comment: Piece of cake... It works... Thanks so much... Dont you want to post an answer for rewarding your efford? :)

Comment: Nah man, thank you for the offer, but it's simply a typo on your side (I think this line is in the doc). You can juste close your question, don't worry !

Comment: Ok, I will do it... Thanks again...

Comment: Well if that bothers you so much, post an answer yourself, I don't mind !

Comment: Ok, hoping your solution helps others after posting my answer. More legible. Thanks mate.

Comment: You can also use a directive to enable/disabled an input when you're using ReactiveForm  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937639/how-to-make-a-disabled-reactive-form-editable-in-angular2

Comment: @Eliseo I tried it. You can check it in my post and it is not working.... Thanks for your answer.... :)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfygpt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting solution after @trichetriche help. Hoping it helps others as it helps me.

**HTML**

```
....
<... ... name="Province" id="name="Province" formControlName="Province" [disabled]="registerForm.get('Province').disabled">
```

**TS**

```
.....
      this.listValues= regions;
      if (this.listValues.length === 0) {
        this.registerForm.get('Province').disable();
      } else {
        this.registerForm.get('Province').enable();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

[disabled]="boolean" (true or false)

[disabled]="listValues.length == 0 ? true : false"

Comment: Not working properly... As far as I am using reactive forms, warning appears... You can check it in the image added in my post. Cheers mate.