# Angular Reactive Forms - Let Nested Child Determine Enable/Disable

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a nested reactive form in angular.

The child has 2 properties and the second one is either enabled or disabled based on the value of the first.

The parent form has an edit button that enables/disables fields through
`this.parentForm.enable()`.

My problem is this enables the second child field no matter what and doesn't use the logic in the child to determine if it should be enabled or disabled.

**What is the suggested approach for reactive forms with enable/disable logic in the children?**  I tried using [disabled] but it didn't work and I received warnings that I shouldn't do this.

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edsopo) with a sample problem.

When `edit` is clicked it should only enable the last input if `Yes` is checked.  It should be disabled if `No` is checked.

Comment: you should put your code in your question.

Comment: @bryan60 instead of in the stack blitz?

Comment: both is recommended, links can go bad in the future but they're helpful now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so add a function like this to your controller:

```
 private setChildState() { 
    // this function gets the ctrl to enable/disable and does so based on the value
    const v = this.parentForm.get('typeDetails').get('identity').value;
    let ctrl = this.parentForm.get('typeDetails').get('identityname');
    if (v === 'yes') {
      ctrl.enable();
    } else {
      ctrl.disable();
    }
 }
```

this is to set your child form enable / disable state, then just add these few lines:

this in your ngOnViewInit()

```
// this listens to value changes and updates form state
this.parentForm.get('typeDetails').get('identity').valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
  this.setChildState();
});
```

and then this in your edit function:

```
this.setChildState();
```

fixed blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwfn35?file=src/app/app.component.ts

EDIT:

if you want to keep this all (mostly) in the child, change your child to this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.identifyForm.get('identity').valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
      this.setState();
    })
  }

  setState() {
    const v = this.identifyForm.get('identity').value;
    let ctrl = this.identifyForm.get('identityname');
    if (v === 'yes') {
      ctrl.enable();
    } else {
      ctrl.disable();
    }
  }
```

then add this to your edit function in the parent:

```
this.childComponent.setState();
```

Comment: This does work but it leaks the logic of the child into the parent.  This child will be used multiple places with the same enable/disable logic each time, so I'd have to duplicate the setChildState in each parent.  Is is possible to do it without having the child logic in each parent?

Comment: In my case, Bryne's solution helped me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Move the Radio Group code to your parent component and subscribe to the changes

based on the value **yes** or **no**

enable and disble child component form control

filed stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kszjwj

Comment: This leaks the child's validation logic into the parent. Becomes a real problem when the child is used in multiple forms.

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is improve the enabled directive of this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937639/how-to-make-a-disabled-reactive-form-editable-in-angular2)

We are going to improve the directive to allow disabled not only the control else all the controls inside a form.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[disableControl]'
})
export class DisableControlDirective {
  @Input() set disableControl(condition: boolean) {
    if (this.ngControl) { //if is an ngControl
      if (condition)
        this.ngControl.control.disable();
      else
        this.ngControl.control.enable();
    }
    if (this.controls) { //if is a formGroup, we ask about the inners controls
      this.controls.forEach((x: any) => {
        let control:boolean=false;
        if (this.innerControl) //we check if the control has
                               //his own DisableControlDirective
          control=(this.innerControl.find(inner=>x==inner.ngControl)!=null)

        if (!control) { //if it has not a own DisabledControlDirective
          if (condition)
            x.control.disable();
          else
            x.control.enable()
        }
      })
    }
  }
  @ContentChildren(NgControl) controls: QueryList<NgControl>
  @ContentChildren(DisableControlDirective)
             innerControl:QueryList<DisableControlDirective>
  //see that make public ngControl to use when check if a innerControl has 
  //the directive
  constructor(@Optional() public ngControl: NgControl) {}
}
```

If we apply the directive to a fromGroup, disabled/enabled all the inners controls. For get the inners control we are using `@ContentChildren(NgControl)`. When we inject NgControl, we need put `@Optional()` because in a FormGroup we has NO NgControl -remember that NgControl is anything that has [formControlName], [NgModel] or [formControl] directive

We need check if our inner controls has no [disableControl] directive. In this case we need leap this control. For this, we need get these controls using `@ContentChildren(DisableControlDirective)` and check it.

Our form becomes very "easy", but we pass as `@Input` the edit mode to the child

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm" [disableControl]="!editMode" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
  <input formControlName="id">
  <input formControlName="name">
  <app-child-component [editMode]="editMode"></app-child-component>
</form>

//and our children component

<form [formGroup]="identifyForm" [disableControl]="!editMode">
  <input type="radio" name="identity" value="yes" formControlName="identity"> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="identity" value="no" formControlName="identity" > No

  <input formControlName="identityname" 
     [disableControl]="!editMode || identifyForm.get('identity').value=='no'">
</form>
```

We can see the final result in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ekkfdd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdisable.directive.ts)