# Custom validator with condition only detect changes once

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `FormGroup` look like this:

```
this.complaint = new FormGroup({
      date: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      isRangeDate: new FormControl(false, Validators.required),
      untilDate: new FormControl(null, rangeDateValidator()),
    });
```

and I have this custom validator `rangeDateValidator`

```
function rangeDateValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    console.log(control?.parent?.get('isRangeDate')?.value)
    return control?.parent?.get('isRangeDate')?.value ? {required: true} : null;
  }
}
```

that basically check if user chose to input range date and if so - it's change the `untilDate` control to be required.
this thing is working only in the first time - `isRangeDate` by default is `false` so it's  no `required` validation added to the control, and when it change to true it's add the `required` to the control, but only once - when I change it back to `isRangeDate: false`, the required validation still attach to it
and I can see in the console that the validator function didn't call, even the `FormGroup` is changed.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find the answer for it in the end:

- the reason the `rangeDateValidator` validator didn't fire the second
  time is that this validator is attached to `untilDate FormControl` so
  it only fires when the `untilDate` value is changed and this has not
  happened because the only field that changed is only the
  `isRangeDate` field, so the validator function didn't call.

so, the answer for it is to add a **custom validator on the `FormGroup`** level (not specific on the `FormControl`), check out this service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComplaintService {
  private readonly complaint: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.complaint = new FormGroup({
      date: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      isRangeDate: new FormControl(false, Validators.required),
      untilDate: new FormControl(null),
      situationDetails: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      whyNotRight: new FormControl(null),
      whatYouDone: new FormControl(null),
      isTrial: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      howCanWeHelp: new FormControl(null),
      isAboutProperty: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      propertyDetails: addressForm(),
      attachments: filesForm()
    }, this.groupValidator());
  }

  groupValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (group: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      if (group?.get('isRangeDate')?.value) {
        group.get('untilDate')?.addValidators(Validators.required)
      } else {
        group.get('untilDate')?.removeValidators(Validators.required)
        group.get('untilDate')?.setErrors(null);
      }

      return group.errors;
    }
  }
}
```

this way the validator function `groupValidator` is fired every change in the `FormGroup` and can add or remove validators from there

hope it helps :)

Comment: Another approach can be simply use Validators.required to the untilDate formControl. Then only disable/enable the formControl according the value of isRangeDate. Rememeber that a formControl [disabled](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlStatus) is not invalid. NOTE: Really it's not a good idea remove and add validators if it's not necessary.

Comment: ok. This is a good solution, but in this one, I'll need to `subscribe` to `isRangeDate` formControll which is less nice.

Comment: Or you can use a directive like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937639/how-to-make-a-disabled-reactive-form-editable-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2):

It does not call you're custom validator because you are changing the `isRangeDate` form and not the `untilDate` form, you only assign the custom validator to the `untilDate` form. Maybe you can call a function after changing the `isRangeDate` form with: `myForm.markAllAsTouched()` or `myForm.valid()`. I think this should revalidate the form and call the custom validator.

Comment: A small addition to this: instead of forcing change detection on the whole form when `isRangeDate` is modified, you can simply call `this.complaint.get('untilDate').updateValueAndValidity()` to trigger the validity check of the `untilDate` control.

Comment: thanks for the good answer! I solve it in other way but is actually same idea - I add custom validator to the entire group instead of the control.

Comment: @ardentia thanks for the addition. Didn't thought of that, even in my code :)

nice, glad to hear. keep up

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because when you manually add false in input box it is taken as a string rather than boolean, so maybe that's why the validation object isn't added to untilDate again.

Comment: it's not an input, it's toggle and value it is a Boolean like it should