# [attr.disabled]=true not working in Reactive Form Angular 15

Tags: angular, forms, reactive, disabled-input, disabled-control

Currently I'm using Angular 15 and in Angular 14 for the disabled input field in reactive form I used `[attr.disabled]="disableField ? true : null"`.

This attribute after I update the Angular version 14 to 15 it's not working

Comment: I tried [disabled]="condition" attribute but its not working

I found another solution is formControlName.disable() but I want to put condition in html code

Comment: use a directive to "disabled", see e.g. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937639/how-to-make-a-disabled-reactive-form-editable-in-angular2/47938138#47938138)

Answer (score 10):

It's a change in Angular 15 that changes the disabled state.

This behavior change was caused by a fix to make `setDisabledState` always called. Previously, using `[attr.disabled]` caused your view to be out of sync with your model.

If you are using *Reactive Forms*? Try setting disabled on your model, not your template. Try `new FormControl({ value: 'foo', disabled: true })`. Or call `myControl.disable()` in `ngOnInit`.
If you want to opt-out of the fix. Make sure you're on **15.1.0** or later and import `FormsModule.withConfig({ callSetDisabledState: 'whenDisabledForLegacyCode' })` (or `ReactiveFormsModule`, if that's what you're using).

Comment: I have added 2 control with same formControlName as per the requirement and  based on condition only one is visible at a time so I need to disabled condition in template